Collar Neighborhood in Lee Smooth Manifolds
In John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, a collar neighborhood of a smooth manifold $M$ with boundary is defined to be a neighborhood $V$ of $\partial M$ that is the image of a smooth embedding $\alpha: [0,1) \times \partial M \to M$ such that $\alpha(0,x)=x$ for all $x \in \partial M$. However, is it necessarily true that $\alpha$ is a diffeomorphism onto $V$? The following results in Lee seem to assume this, but I can't figure out how to show this.
The issue is that $[0,1) \times \partial M$ and $M$ both have boundaries, so we can't apply results that depend on the rank theorem. I believe this could be remedied by knowing that we can embed any smooth manifold with boundary into a smooth manifold without boundary, but this result in turns depends on what I'm currently asking being true, for Lee makes this diffeomorphism assumption in proving this fact (see Errata to Thm 9.26).
Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you :)

It is a nice exercise to check that the local diffeomorphism theorem holds for manifolds with boundary.

@MoisheKohan To be precise, what is the result you are referring to? I know that, for example, it is not necessarily true for a smooth map $f:M \to N$ between manifolds with boundary that if $df_p$ is invertible, then $f$ is a local diffeomorphism at $p$. For example, look at the inclusion of half-space into Euclidean space (as Lee does). Is it true, however, that any smooth immersion which is a homeomorphism (between manifolds with boundary) is necessarily a diffeomorphism? How would one show this if so?

You have to assume that boundary maps to boundary, of course.

Here is the desired theorem. Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth manifolds and $f: M \to N$ a smooth map such that $f(\partial M) = \partial N$. Suppose $p \in M$ is such that $df_p$ is invertible. Then $f$ is a local diffeomorphism at $p$.
Proof. If $p \in \mathrm{int}\, M$, then simply apply the result for manifolds without boundary to the smooth map $f: \mathrm{int}\, M \to \mathrm{int}\, N$. Otherwise, $p \in \partial M$. By taking smooth charts at $p$ and $f(p)$, we can assume that $M = N = \mathbb H^n$ and $p = f(p) = 0$. We can find a smooth function $g: U \to \mathbb R^n$ on a neighborhood $U$ of $0$ in $\mathbb R^n$ such that $g$ extends $f$ on $U \cap \mathrm{int}\, \mathbb H^n$. Then $dg_0$ is invertible, so we can assume $U$ is small enough that $g$ is a diffeomorphism onto a neighborhood $V$ of $0$ in $\mathbb R^n$.
Now, the assumption $f(\partial \mathbb H^n) = \partial \mathbb H^n$ implies that $g$ is a diffeomorphism of $U - \partial \mathbb H^n$ onto $V - \partial \mathbb H^n$. In particular, $g$ is continuous, so it must map connected components into connected components. Since $g$ is bijective, it follows that $g$, and hence $f$, maps $U \cap \mathbb H^n$ diffeomorphically onto the open subset $V \cap \mathbb H^n$ of $\mathbb H^n$. Hence, $f$ is a local diffeomorphism at $p$, as desired. //
See also Is a map with invertible differential that maps boundary to boundary a local diffeomorphism?.

Your proof is the same as the one in the linked answer.
